# Passing $event value from [ngStyle] to .TS method

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to pass the $event variable from the html to the .ts.

Inside the (click)="pruebaSwal($event)" is working fine,
but inside the [style.background-color] is where problem occurs, throwing a:
*"ERROR ReferenceError: $event is not defined"*

**html component**

```
<tr>
  <input
    type="button"
    value="{{indice}}" 
    id="cp{{contador()}}"
    (click)="pruebaSwal($event)"  <==this one works fine
    [style.background-color]="colorStatus(item.id, $event)">  <== i catch the id, but NOT the $event
</tr>
```

**ts component**

```
colorStatus(_id, _event){

        let cambio =  this.allActivity[_id] //this works fine
        let ivi = _event.path[0].id         //not finding the _event var
           
         switch (_id) {
           ...some case functions
           }
```

Comment: What do you want to pass as $event?

Comment: I would like to mention there, that using functions directly inside our templates should be the last choice. This functions called on every rendering and they will be the cause of performance issues, especially when not combined with `OnPush` detection strategy.

Answer (score 5):

$event is passed to component only in event binding (example: click, focus etc.) and includes information about the event.
In your case you are not using event binding but property binding, there is no event, that's why you get the error: "ERROR ReferenceError: $event is not defined"

Comment: i guess that is what is causing the problem.
but, is there any other way of passing that value? not using the $event

Comment: Value of what exactly do you want to pass?

Comment: There is an option to use template reference variables that provide direct access to the element within the html. see [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)

Comment: close one, but it pass it like:   
cp{{contador()}}

and i need the resulting value when the method gets it... in browser ends up like:
id="cp001"

thats the value i need

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood correctly, but maybe it will give some ideas:

```
<input *ngIf="'cp' + contador() as id"
    type="button"
    value="{{indice}}" 
    [id]="id"
    (click)="pruebaSwal($event)"  <==this one works fine
    [style.background-color]="colorStatus(item.id, id)">
```

P.S. calling functions in template is considered a bad practice https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496